# Save an array of arrays to database

Tags: php, joomla

After lots of searching and failing after trying.. i am posting this question here..

After half part of my actual query [here][1] i am not able to save the resulting array of arrays to the database..

Initially i had an array of inputs which i turned into array of arrays of inputs now my save function looks something like this

```
function store()
{
        foreach($post['cats'] as $cat)  {

        $query = 'insert into #__joomd_item_cat values('.$cat.', '.$row->id.')';
        $this->_db->setQuery( $query );

        if(!$this->_db->query())    {
            $obj->error = $this->_db->getErrorMsg();
            return $obj;
        }

    }
}
```

now, how do i modify it to get my array of arrays into database..

This function is triggered by a serialized method.. so please recheck your answers and comments

```
function save(task) {
var data = $jd("form[name='<?php echo $array['editform']; ?>']").serializeArray();
    $jd.ajax({
          url: "<?php echo $url; ?>",
          type: "POST",
          dataType:"json",
          data: data,
          beforeSend: function()    {
            $jd(".poploadingbox").show();
          },
          complete: function()  {
            $jd(".poploadingbox").hide();
          },
          success: function(res)    {

            savesuccess(res);

          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)   {
            alert(textStatus);                 
          }
    });
```

}

```
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583375/add-input-fields-dynamically-but-fields-are-generated-by-external-php-functions/11583597#11583597
```

Comment: The easy way is to serialize (see `serialize()`, http://php.net/serialize) your array and save that, but it limits your ability to manipulate the data in the database.

Comment: all i can figure out is use the function serialize() which cab be used like type:serialize($_POST); in ajax in the sending function, but retrieval is still not clear.. To save them i still need an array, which all confuses me.. Can you help

Answer (score 3):

You can [`serialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) it and then [`unserialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it upon retrieval.

Comment: Being a learner of the basics, all i can figure out is use the function serialize() which cab be used like `type:serialize($_POST);` in ajax in the sending function, but retrieval is still not clear..

To save them i still need an array, which all confuses me

Comment: Am sorry, the things were already serialized, now how would you want me to proceed..