# value of webpage output integrating into javascript

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js

I'm currently using a d3.js graph which is written in javascript. You can find the original graph here (view the source to see the javascript coding):
http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/area-gradient.html

The last line of the following code seems to calculate the maximum value of the Y-axis:

```
  // Compute the maximum price.
  x.domain([new Date(1999, 0, 1), new Date(2003, 0, 0)]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
```

I'm not happy with the way it gets calculated.
I have no knowledge of javascripting at all, but I found out that I could replace the "function(d) { return d.value; })" part by an integer and it would show me a graph which looks better.

I've made a php page which will output the highest value which is in my data set.

My question is now, how can I get the output of the page on the location of this function?
It should like this:

```
y.domain([0, <webpage value>]);
```

Thanks a lot for your help,

Greggy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution via [jquery ajax get responsetext from http url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152692/jquery-ajax-get-responsetext-from-http-url) .

```
var response = ''; $.ajax({ type: "GET",url: "maxval.php", async: false,success : function(text){response = text;} });
y.domain([0, response]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check `getElementById`, depending on how your output looks like.

```
y.domain([0, getElementById("myPersonalOutput").value]);
```

Where your page would contain something like

```
<div id="myPersonalOutput">123456</div>
```

Mixing PHP and jscript is often times confusing and / or not possible.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not mixing both. The graph is for example in graph.html and the maximum value is displayed in maxval.php. So, somehow I would like to have a solution where javascript would call the maxval.php and output the value which is displayed in the page.

Comment: A sample output of maxval.php is for example: 41.464447

Comment: I see, are you able to use jquery on your webpage? With jquery I could see the `$.ajax()` function working for you

Comment: Ok, but how should the coding look like? I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938180/how-to-get-the-html-of-a-div-on-another-page-with-jquery-ajax with some more info. I've added a div with the id 'content' in the php page. In the html page I've change the javascript to y.domain([0, $.ajax({url:maxval.php, type:'GET', success: function(data){$('#content').html($(data).find('#content').html());}});]); ...but doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, I think my first idea was not the best one @Greggy

Comment: Another comment, because i could not edit my previous one @Greggy. Another try: an easier way would be using the `$.get()` function. See: [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). This would look like `y.domain([0, $.get("maxval.php", function( data ) { return data; });]);`  P.S.: this is not the safest way to transmit data, please be aware of this!

Comment: Hmm, it looks like this one is also not working. When I put it in an alert, it doesn't show me anything. alert($.get("maxval.php", function( data ) { return data; }););

Comment: Another try: `var a = $.get("maxval.php", function( data ) { return data; });
alert (a);` This gives me a pop-up with: [object Object], so if I get this correct, it should be converted somehow to a float or double.